# Getting errors while building an Unity app in android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am trying to build an `Unity app` for android but I am getting too many errors. Below are the error details from my Unit app.

This is error 1:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to build apk.
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M     -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:\Users\HMM\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "D:\Program Files\Unity     2018.1.0b13\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native     Method)
    at     java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAc    cessorImpl.java:62)
    at     java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Delegating    MethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at SDKMain.main(SDKMain.java:130)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/BASE64Encoder
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.build.SignedJarBuilder.<init>    (SignedJarBuilder.java:177)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.init(ApkBuilder.java:446)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.<init>(ApkBuilder.java:422)
    at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.<init>(ApkBuilder.java:362)
    at UnityApkBuilder.<init>(UnityApkBuilder.java:214)
    at UnityApkBuilder.main(UnityApkBuilder.java:34)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.BASE64Encoder
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:566)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    ... 11 more
]
stdout[

]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun     (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p,     UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit     waitingForProcessToExit,     System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi,         UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit,         System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandInternal (System.String         javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32     memoryMB, System.String workingdir,     UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit,     System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommand (System.String javaExe,     System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB,     System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit     waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()
```

This is Error 2:

```
 "Build completed with a result of 'Failed'
    UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()
```

Then I get another error:

```
Build completed with a result of 'Failed'
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()
```

Can some one help me resolve the error. Any suggestions are always welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by downgrading Java JDK to v8 from v10 :3

Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 1):

This error can be cause due to many things.

1) Update JDK

2) Check Java Path.

3) Update Android SDK

4) Delete duplicate .jar file in unity asset folder under plugins folder.

5) Check target version in AndroidManifest.xml and Player Settings which should be same.